# Problem with creating form that appears on every page in Symfony 6

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms, symfony6

I want to have a form that appears on the navigation bar on each page. I don't want to write the form in every single route, because I want to do it in a shorter way.

What I tried is to create a function that is responsible only for creating form. This function is called in a base.html.twig file, so the form is visible on all pages that extend this file. The only problem is that after submitting the form, no instruction inside the if statement is executed. When I click submit button, page refreshes.

Part of the **base.html.twig** file:

```
{{ render(controller('App\\Controller\\FrontController::searchForm')) }}
```

**searchForm** function:

```
public function searchForm(Request $request): Response
{
    $searchForm = $this->createForm(NavbarFormType::class);
    $searchForm->handleRequest($request);

    if ($searchForm->isSubmitted() && $searchForm->isValid())
    {
        $data = $searchForm->getData();
        $search = $data['search'];
        return $this->redirectToRoute('search_results', [
            'search' => $search,
        ]);
    }

    return $this->render('front/search_form.html.twig', [
        'searchForm' => $searchForm,
    ]);
}
```

**search_form.html.twig** file:

```
{{ form_start(searchForm) }}
    {{ form_row(searchForm.search) }}
    {{ form_row(searchForm.submit) }}
{{ form_end(searchForm) }}
```

**searchResults** function:

```
#[Route('/search-results', name: 'search_results')]
public function searchResults(Request $request): Response
{
    $search = $request->query->get('search');
    dump($search);
    return $this->render('front/search_results.html.twig');
}
```

I will appreciate for each respond with my form submitting issue

Comment: I'm pretty sure your search form is posting to whatever page it happens to be on.  I am guessing the action is blank.  You need to define a route for searchForm and then set the url for the form.  If you don't think this is the problem then please update your question with the rendered form element.

Comment: Defining a route and setting the url solved my problem, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cerad's comment solved my problem. I edited two files

To **searchForm** function I added route

```
#[Route('/search-form', name: 'search_form')]
```

In **search_form.html.twig** I changed the first line

```
{{ form_start(searchForm, {'action': path('search_results'), 'method': 'GET'}) }}
```

Comment: Just for info, there is also a [$form->setAction](https://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html#changing-the-action-and-http-method) method that saves your from messing around in twig. Some find it cleaner to do this sort of thing in the controller.  Your choice of course.